# Match letter to corresponding number in list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm looking at making a program, that when the user inputs a name as an argument it matches each letter to a corresponding number stored in a list.

For eg:

```
def nameNumbers(name):
    alphabetList = ['Aa', 8.17, 'Bb', 1.49, 'Cc', 2.78, 'Dd', 4.25, 
  'Ee', 12.70, 'Ff', 2.23, 'Gg', 2.02, 'Hh', 6.09, 'Ii', 6.97, 
  'Jj', 0.15, 'Kk', 0.77, 'Ll', 4.03, 'Mm', 2.41, 'Nn', 6.75, 
  'Oo', 7.51, 'Pp', 1.93, 'Qq', 0.10, 'Rr', 5.99, 'Ss', 6.33, 
  'Tt', 9.06, 'Uu', 2.76, 'Vv', 0.98, 'Ww', 2.36, 'Xx', 0.15, 
  'Yy', 1.97, 'Zz', 0.07]
```

So if I was to pass in "Adam" it would return:

```
8.17
4.25
8.17
2.41
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use a dictionary to map letters to numbers. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dictionary which has alphabet character as key as value as the integer

```
def nameNumbers(name):
    alphabetList = ['Aa', 8.17, 'Bb', 1.49, 'Cc', 2.78, 'Dd', 4.25, 
  'Ee', 12.70, 'Ff', 2.23, 'Gg', 2.02, 'Hh', 6.09, 'Ii', 6.97, 
  'Jj', 0.15, 'Kk', 0.77, 'Ll', 4.03, 'Mm', 2.41, 'Nn', 6.75, 
  'Oo', 7.51, 'Pp', 1.93, 'Qq', 0.10, 'Rr', 5.99, 'Ss', 6.33, 
  'Tt', 9.06, 'Uu', 2.76, 'Vv', 0.98, 'Ww', 2.36, 'Xx', 0.15, 
  'Yy', 1.97, 'Zz', 0.07]
    dic = { alphabetList[i][1]: alphabetList[i+1] for i in range(0,len(alphabetList),2)}

    for i in name:
        print(dic[i.lower()])

nameNumbers('adam')
```

or you need to find the index of the each character, in your list each character is as upper letter + lowe letter ie `Aa` or `Bb` , then use list.index to find the index location and access that next element of that index in list

```
def nameNumbers(name):
    alphabetList = ['Aa', 8.17, 'Bb', 1.49, 'Cc', 2.78, 'Dd', 4.25, 
      'Ee', 12.70, 'Ff', 2.23, 'Gg', 2.02, 'Hh', 6.09, 'Ii', 6.97, 
      'Jj', 0.15, 'Kk', 0.77, 'Ll', 4.03, 'Mm', 2.41, 'Nn', 6.75, 
      'Oo', 7.51, 'Pp', 1.93, 'Qq', 0.10, 'Rr', 5.99, 'Ss', 6.33, 
      'Tt', 9.06, 'Uu', 2.76, 'Vv', 0.98, 'Ww', 2.36, 'Xx', 0.15, 
      'Yy', 1.97, 'Zz', 0.07]

    for alphabet in name:
        to_find = "{}{}".format(alphabet.upper(), alphabet.lower())
        print(alphabetList[alphabetList.index(to_find)+1])

nameNumbers('adam')
```

Comment: Adding on to this, if you can be bothered, you could replace the list with `alphabetDict = {'a' : 8.17, 'b' : 1.49, 'c' : 2.78, ..., 'z' : 0.07 }` to skip the list to dict conversion step everytime the program is run

Comment: @JolonB yeah this can be done this way , i just propse this solution keeping OP code more preference

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, my uni is using an environment called JES to program in and it doesn't accept either of the pieces of code you've given. I'll keep looking at the textbook that goes with it. I can't find it in there though.

Comment: @Ollie-cf if this is python only this should work , in your case add `jython` tag to the question, that might help

Comment: @sahasrara62 thanks, I thought the code was the same, just that Jython was written in Java. I'm very new to this! Any hints on how I would do it in Jython?

Comment: sorry, i am nob in java and jython

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like:

```
def nameNumbers(name):
    alphabetList = ['a', 8.17, 'b', 1.49, 'c', 2.78, 'd', 4.25, 'e', 12.70, 'f', 2.23, 
    'g', 2.02, 'h', 6.09, 'i', 6.97, 'j', 0.15, 'k', 0.77, 'l', 4.03, 'm', 2.41, 'n', 
    6.75, 'o', 7.51, 'p', 1.93, 'q', 0.10, 'r', 5.99, 's', 6.33, 't', 9.06, 'u', 2.76, 
    'v', 0.98, 'w', 2.36, 'x', 0.15, 'y', 1.97, 'z', 0.07]
    for letter in name.lower():
        print(alphabetList[alphabetList.index(letter)+1])

nameNumbers('Adam')
```

No need for the uppercase of each letter if you use ".lower()".

Comment: It's better to use a dict here. No reason to reinvent the dict :)